# you don't have authorization to view this page

Tags: sharepoint-server, api

I can't open web services link in SharePoint

Getting this error when open http://site/_vti_bin

> you don't have authorization to view this page

If someone can help me. I will be appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to that page from a browser? That URL is for the REST API to make requests to SharePoint and isn't a webpage for viewing. You use that URL when making calls to the various services under the API like http://site/_vti_bin/ListData.svc

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes from browser,  I want to display all the available sharepoint webservices,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what version you are running but here is a general list of web services available under _VTI_BIN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878586(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: @Arin this link also useful for sharepoint 2013 version?

Comment: Seems like there are not too many differences but I'm sure 2013 brings new services as well.